# C++ - I want to select the first two digits after a decimal point and check to see if they are the same and not 0

Tags: c++, digits, decimal-point

I'm trying to get the first two digits after the decimal point of a number and the check to see if they are equal to each other and, at the same time, not equal to 0.

**I know how to do the checking** stuff but **I have no idea how to select the first two digits after the decimal point**.

Using setprecision would give me the number entirely, not just the two digits after the decimal point.

For example:

```
i = 3.141592
cout << setprecision(3) << i
```

would output 3.14, **but I only want 14**.

Comment: How about multiply by 100 to get 314.1592 and then cast to int which would yield 314 and finally modulo 100 which would result in 14 ?

Comment: I was just about to write that. lol

Comment: `setprecision` just changes how the number is displayed. If you want the two digits you need something else than a output manipulator

Comment: You do realize that if you are dealing with floats then you may end up with very unintuitive results?

Comment: To make that concrete: What are the first two digits of after the decimal point for `(1.0/3) * 3` ?

Comment: Where does this number come from?  If it is user input, it might be best to read the value as a string rather than a number, and look for the two characters after the decimal seperator.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use the floor function from the **std** library

```
int(i*100 - (floor(i))*100)
```

Here is a good example webpage: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/math/floor

Comment: If he is after the first two _digits_ the result should be casted to int anyway, otherwise you end up with a floating point value. Edit: although to clarify, I didn't downvote your answer.

Comment: Yes you are right. Sorry, it needs to be cast to int as well. I updated the answer

Comment: @noobuntu Can you guarantee that the result will be correct no matter what `i` is? Because, you know, floating point arithmetics. This is not obvious to me at all. Does it depend on the underlying architecture?

Comment: @freakish can you provide an example where this would fail? I am open to being wrongbut I do not see how this would fail

Comment: @noobuntu Well, I don't have one. I'm just worried that this may fail in some weird cases. There are lots of floats, you know. :D The problem is that `*` and `-` are not "exact" in the sense they are not preserving decimal expansions (classical `0.1 + 0.2 != 0.3`). This might be ok, I just don't see it now. Anyway, if correctness is a requirement I would not use floats to begin with.

Comment: @noobuntu I believe it fails with 1.15 for example. You need to apply rounding somewhere for this to be a robust solution.

Comment: @MarkRansom: That's tricky.  Presumably 1.15 is actually 1.149999976 or similar - but you wouldn't want to return `15` if the user entered 1.49999.

Comment: @MartinBonner actually you would, if the question was properly specified. `cout` with `setprecision` will do rounding, so `1.49999` would be displayed as `1.50`.

Comment: @freakish I found one example right away, then discovered a few more that would actually give incorrect results for the question: 9.12, 9.45, 9.78.

Answer (score 0):

You could implement a function, that returns the digits as an integer.

```
#include <math.h>

int digits_after_decimal_point(double number, unsigned int precision){
    double trunc = number - static_cast<int>(number); //3,141 > 0,141
    return static_cast<int>(trunc * pow(10,precision));
}
```

Example call:

```
std::cout << digits_after_decimal_point(3.14159, 3) << std::endl;
```

Output:

```
141
```

But the problem is, checking digits of integers is (without using a bunch of `%` operations) pretty undoable. So for checking, you could convert the result into a `std::string` (using `std::ostringstream`) and than you can compare specific indexes.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply take out the 2 digits after the decimal point by multiplying the number by 100 , and now you have those 2 digits just before the decimal which you can extract by first type-casting the number into integer and then taking mod with 100.
for eg : 345.897 is the number
multiply by 100 : 34589.7
now typecast to integer : 34589
now mod with 100 :  89
This can be generalized as if the number is x .
Last 2 digits are : y = ((int)(x*100))%100;
And if you want to get these digits individually to compare again take mod with 10 and divide by 10 twice.
for eg : number is now y
digit1 = y%10
divide the y by 10
digit2 = y%10
compare digit1 and digit2 as you want